# Real time balance calculation

Tags: mysql, sql-server, real-time

We want to show real time sms balance for client. We offered prepaid system, suppose an user sending 20000 SMS, after sending each sms we have to deduct it from balance... in this way if we get his balance is insufficient then we will stop sending sms. We always update the user profile table using sql transaction  for balance.

we sending sms in millisecond , and updating the all user profile (1) table using sql transaction then this table will be very busy..

Can you explain clearly so that we can implement it for better performance in database.

Comment: 1. mysql and sql-server are very different 2. you havn't asked any question

Comment: i need solution for both DB and wanted to know the algorithm.